# Is “les vacances avoir fini” correct?

Tags: conjugaison

If I want to say: "The vacations have finished" in French, is the following correct?

> *Les vacances avoir fini*

Comment: Answer on which auxiliary to use (*être* or *avoir*) is **context dependent** and what you said in English is not enough. So please edit your sentence and explain 1- what you want to express -by finishing your sentence for example, it does not matter if you make mistakes, we'll correct you and explain. 2- Make clear what tense you want to use (I think it's the present, but just in case). If I may ask, are you an English native? If you aren't make sure what you want to say in English is accurate, if not we might mislead you.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to say is "The holidays are over", then a correct French translation is:

```
Les vacances sont finies.
```